# crontab job not working properly

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, cron

I was trying to use my pi and a bluetooth speaker as an alarm clock.

I've setup a cronjob by doing

```
sudo crontab -e
```

in the crontab file, I added

```
40 8 * * 1-5 /home/XXXXX/alarm.sh &> alarm.log
```

the alarm.sh script is as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
bluez-test-audio connect MAC_OF_SPEAKER
bluez-test-device trusted MAC_OF_SPEAKER yes
mplayer -ao alsa:device=clock MY_MUSIC.m4a
```

The problem now is that the cronjob won't work. If I run the script manually, the speaker plays the .m4a file correctly. But cronjob won't execute at 08:40 in the morning.

Please give me some advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as @joan mentioned in the [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/crontab-job-not-working-properly/32868?noredirect=1#comment42346_32868), I need to *"**provide full path to files in cron jobs**."*

Cron jobs were executed, but since I didn't provide full path to alarm.log, it is not in my user home directory.

So what I did to fix the problem:

1.change cronjob to

```
40 8 * * 1-5 /home/XXXXX/alarm.sh > /home/XXXXX/alarm.log 2>&1
```

redirect output was not necessary, but it helped me to find out where went wrong.

2.change the alarm.sh script to

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
bluez-test-audio connect MAC_OF_SPEAKER
bluez-test-device trusted MAC_OF_SPEAKER yes
mplayer -ao alsa:device=clock FULL_PATH_TO_MY_MUSIC/MY_MUSIC.m4a //full path is needed
bluez-test-audio disconnect MAC_OF_SPEAKER
```

The music played as scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the cron service with

```
sudo service cron restart
```

after editing your cronjob.

If this doesn't help, try using a simple echo bash script as a cronjob.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The echo script was not executed...

Comment: Try: 40 8 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/XXXXX/alarm.sh &> alarm.log

Comment: OK, I added */1 * * * * ~/echo_hello.sh > echo.log, the file echo.log was created and has "hello" in it. But if I just register ~/echo_hello.sh, nothing gets printed on the screen.

Comment: I checked my own cronjobs and found out that I always specified "/bin/bash" like mentioned above. Another possibility that could help is using "crontab -e" instead of "sudo crontab -e".

Comment: I tried both "crontab -e" and "sudo crontab -e", none of them seem to work...

Comment: Did you try the "/bin/bash" hint?

Comment: yes, I did tried that..

Comment: @Eniaczz You should always give full paths to files in cron jobs. For instance mplayer -ao alsa:device=clock MY_MUSIC.m4a assumes that MY_MUSIC.m4a is in the current directory.  I have no idea what the default current directory is for a cron job, it's not the directory containing MY_MUSIC.m4a though.

Comment: @joan Actually, that solves my problem!! I didn't realize that "sudo crontab -e" jobs will be executed by root, not by my user with sudo privilege. Thanks!!